# Conexão e consulta de dados em banco de dados Oracle e envio de dados para banco SQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, oracle, asp.net-core

Bom dia Pessoal,
Estou precisando de uma ajuda. Preciso acessar uma base de dados em Oracle onde tenho uma tabela com algumas informações que desejo enviar para um banco de dados SQL Server, entre eles estou utilizando a linguagem C#. Gostaria de saber qual método vocês utilizam para fazer essa passagem de dados sem que seja feito a exclusão ou alteração das informações na base Oracle, pois pensei em utilizar  "CRUD" para fazer isso mais acredito que não tenha lógica e nem necessidade disso, deve haver formas melhores para executar o procedimento.

Comment: *"CRUD"* signfica *Create, Read, Update and Delete*, então não é o que precisa... e CRUD é algo que não está bem relacionado ao seu cenário, seria mais fácil usar alguma estratégia de migração, como por exemplo o *SQL Server Migration Assistant*

Comment: Essa migração e feita de forma constante, pois sempre ira chegar informações nesta tabela que estou me referindo a você.

Comment: por isso mesmo era melhor usar algo como o *SQL Server Integration Services"*, e executar automaticamente a nível do banco de dados (um *job* por exemplo) no lugar de escrever código pra tratar disso. Dê uma olhada nessas soluções que são melhores que escrever programas, a não ser que tenha algo que não seja possível de transformar (que é bem difícil de existir) numa ferramenta de transformação ou importação de banco de dados já pronta

Comment: Teria algum link para me ajudar, apenas para dar um norte no assunto?

Comment: @marc_teixeira dê uma olhada em ETL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opções são:

- Pode faze-lo direto pelo SQL Server usando SSMA
  https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssma/oracle/migrating-oracle-databases-to-sql-server-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver16.
- Criando um Job no Oracle e no SQL Server para fazer exportação e
  importação.
  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/PLAUG/ch05s19.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-ver16.

- Criando uma aplicação (C#) console que importados de um banco e
  insere no outro.
- Conectando Oracle diretamente ao SQL Server.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-an-oracle-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Muito obrigado Nilson pela ajuda, irei verificar todos os links e ver qual deles melhor se enquadra no cenário ao qual estou desenvolvendo.